# Removing properties PREBINDING & GCC_ENABLE_FIX_AND_CONTINUE

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

While compiling on XCODE 4.2 (IOS 5.0), I got warnings that following properties are not used in the build file

```
GCC_ENABLE_FIX_AND_CONTINUE = NO;
PREBINDING = NO;
```

I did not get these warnings with XCODE 4.0.

What does these properties do and is it safe to get rid of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove them safely by clicking on the issue navigator. You will see a yellow warning sign in front of the Xcode project file. Click on that warning sign, Xcode will prompt you to upgrade the Xcode project file to match with the Xcode 3.2 settings. 
It should be safe to remove them as a matter of fact.